# visual studio cpp - add debug print to each line

Tags: c++, debugging, printf, visual-studio-2022

So, I would like to have a printf with line number for each line in my code.

For example :

> ```
>                 while (i < receivedDataSize
>                     && ((char*)peer->receiveBuffer)[i] == ' ')
>                 {
>                     i++;
>                 }
> ```

should be :

> ```
>                 printf("line 1");
>                 while (i < receivedDataSize
>                     && ((char*)peer->receiveBuffer)[i] == ' ')
>                 {
>                     printf("line 2");
>                     i++;
>                 }
> ```

Is there anything that can add these printf line with line number automatically ?

Thanks

Comment: Question: Is this to see how far the program gets before crashing or other failure? If so, have you tried stepping through the program with a debugger?

Comment: Automatically as in no effort on your part, no. You have to do this the hard way which is why I recommend using a debugger above.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-line-directive-c-cpp?view=msvc-170

Comment: So this is an EFI runtime app, hard to debug it with qemu because I need firmware